# Cannot get data out of the subscribe method in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm gonna be brief and simple in this question.
In my project, I have a service component with this method :

```
@Injectable()
export class HolidaysServiceService {
  constructor(private http: Http){};

 getAllHolidays(): Observable<Holidays[]> {
  return this.http
  .get(this.path + '/findAll')
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }
}
```

and I have another component with this method :

```
    export class fooComponent implements OnInit {

    tab_jf: Holidays[] = [];

   constructor( private service: HolidaysServiceService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribeToService();
    console.log(this.tab_jf);
     // returns empty table

   }

 subscribeToService() {
   this.service.getAllHolidays().subscribe(
   (hol: Holidays[]) => {
    this.tab_jf = hol ;
    }
     console.log(this.tab_jf);
        // returns the correct data
     console.log(this.tab_jf.length); 
       // return the correct length : 24  

    }, err => console.error(err));
  console.log(this.tab_jf.length);
   // returns length = 0
 }
}
```

My aim is to have this.tab_jf availaible in my component all the time.

The problem is that I can't get the data outside the subscribe() method of the subscribeToService().

Ps : It in not possible to use subscribe() outside of subscribeToService() from a processing point of view (thousands of data to loop over).

Comment: the problem is that your `console.log` in the `ngOnInit()` isn't yet filled with data. It will run right after you've called the `subscribeToService()` function. It will have data when the service emits it to the subscriber.

Comment: Yes exactly, it's an async problem i think, but can i do something to  get the tab , because I need to use it in other methods ?

Comment: Well you can call your methods from the subscriber, as one option.

Comment: thank you, but i'm looking for another solution

Comment: Anyone?still can't resolve it